# How do I list all installed programs?

Tags: application

How do I list both programs that came with my distribution and those I manually installed?

Comment: Which distribution? Each distribution has different installing tools.

Comment: Hm, I'm interested in Red Hat, Ubuntu, and cygwin. Is there a distribution-free way to list the programs with some command line argument?

Comment: No, there isn't, as the package managers differ.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

That depends on your distribution.

- Aptitude-based distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, etc): `dpkg -l`
- RPM-based distributions (Fedora, RHEL, etc): `rpm -qa`
- pkg*-based distributions (OpenBSD, FreeBSD, etc): `pkg_info`
- Portage-based distributions (Gentoo, etc): `equery list` or [`eix -I`](http://eix.berlios.de/)
- pacman-based distributions (Arch Linux, etc): `pacman -Q`
- Cygwin: `cygcheck --check-setup --dump-only *`
- Slackware: `slapt-get --installed`

All of these will list the *packages* rather than the *programs* however. If you truly want to list the programs, you probably want to list the executables in your `$PATH`, which can be done like so using bash's `compgen`:

```
compgen -c
```

Or, if you don't have `compgen`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=: read -ra dirs_in_path <<< "$PATH"

for dir in "${dirs_in_path[@]}"; do
    for file in "$dir"/*; do
        [[ -x $file && -f $file ]] && printf '%s\n' "${file##*/}"
    done
done
```

Comment: And for RPM based systems (Red Hat, SuSE, CentOS, etc.): `rpm -qa`

Comment: Doesn't Fedora nowadays use `dnf`. I do not know the exact command.

Comment: I am using an Aptitude-based distributions. What should I add to this command to know how much space this program takes up?

Comment: Debian / Ubuntu is `dkpg -l | grep ^ii`.

Comment: @Rolf, you mean dPKg

Comment: Yes, Harkály Gergő, `dpkg`. It was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hrmph... The BSDs are not Linux distributions...

Comment: @Kusalananda Huh? At no point in this answer does it say that BSDs are Linux distributions, but they are *distributions*. That's literally what the "D" in BSD stands for.

Comment: It would be better to distinguish between package managers instead of "distributions". NetBSD's pkgsrc runs on any Linux, and some package managers can be used on multiple Uinces.

Answer (score 13):

*Answering the second part of the question (nothing really to be added to [Chris' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20979/how-do-i-list-all-installed-programs/20981#20981) for the first part)*:

There is generally **no** way of listing manually installed programs and their components. This is not recorded anywhere if you didn't use a package manager. All you can do is find the binaries in standard locations (like Chris suggested) and in a similar way, **guess** where *some* libraries or *some* manual pages etc. came from. That is why, whenever possible, **you should always install programs using your package manager**.

Answer (score 9):

All the other answers (so far) deal with packages and binaries.
If you mean "desktop applications", the ones that appear in your start menu, you can try:

```
ls /usr/share/applications | awk -F '.desktop' ' { print $1}' -
```

More solutions in [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/433609/how-can-i-list-all-applications-installed-in-my-system).

Comment: That's not true. My answer doesn't list packages at all and not only binaries but shell scripts too.

Answer (score 8):

Programs should be reachable via the PATH, so just list everything in the path:

```
ls ${PATH//:/ }
```

Expect a result of about 3k-4k programs.

To exclude a probable minority of false positives, you may refine the approach:

```
for d in ${PATH//:/ } ; do 
    for f in $d/* ; do  
        test -x $f && test -f $f && echo $f
    done
done
```

It didn't make a difference for me.

Comment: Note that this will also potentially list various non-programs as well (subdirectories of directories in `$PATH`, etc).

Comment: I added a test, but it didn't make a difference for me (how useful is a directory in a directory in the path, which isn't itself in the path?). But for cases, where you rely on correctness, it might be useful.

Comment: awesome! I wasn't able to know version of Linux ( long story - but nothing criminal ) but this code saved my day :)